# create user audit trail in microsoft excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, audit-trail

I need to create a basic user audit trail in Excel 2010 tracking changes to certain cells by different users not signing into a PC (shared PC)

Comment: There's not enough detail here.  What exactly do you want to track?

Comment: Please try to explain your problem more clearly, so that you can get a specific answer to your problem. Questions of *I-need-this* kind are generally too broad and difficult to answer accurately.

Answer (score 0):

The following macro monitors changes to cells **A2** thru **A20**

If a user changes any of these cells, the username and date are recorded in the cell's comment

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim s As String
    s = Now & vbCrLf & Environ("UserName")
        With Target
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment s
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```