# How to set a value into a cell if any changes are made to any cell in the row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, updates

I want to know how to set value of a cell (in my scenario it's last cell in the row) if any cell value is changed or deleted.

I want in such a way that when a user changes/ deletes the value of any cell in the corresponding row, last cell should have a "TRUE" value same moment.(in simpler term changes indicator in excel row)

I tried 'Track' option but couldn't find any condition which will read it and mark last cell as "TRUE" before saving the file.

Comment: You would need to use VBA to achieve this. Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948585/create-user-audit-trail-in-microsoft-excel-2010

Answer (score 1):

Adding an event on the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Long

    If Target.Column < 10 Then
        x = Target.Row
        Range("A1").Offset(x, 10).Value = True
    End If
End Sub
```

considering the last column in the row are 10.
After, if you want to make something, add the code in the Workbook event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
```